# PHP Ajax Success Returns Empty Value

Tags: php, ajax

Good Evening,
I'm creating a website for the job and I am having several problems with Ajax.
This is a function I'm already using, but in this case, it doesn't work. It gives me an empty value as a result.

This is the script.js

```js
$('#nomeCorso').change(function() {
    var tipoCorsi = $('#tipoCorsi').val();
    var nomeCorso = $('#nomeCorso').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        //dataType: 'json',
        url: '../php/elaborazione_dati.php',
        data: {
            nomeCorso: nomeCorso,
            tipoCorsi: tipoCorsi
        },
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById("elencoCorsi").innerHTML = data;
            alert(data);
        }
    });
})
```

And this elaborazione_dati.php

```php
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'nomeCorso' ] ) && isset( $_POST[ 'tipoCorsi' ] ) )  {
      include "connection.php";
      $corsi = $_POST[ 'nomeCorso' ];
      $tipoCorsi = $_POST[ 'tipoCorsi' ];
      $querys = "SELECT * FROM `Corsi` WHERE `Tipo corso` = '" . $corsi . "' AND `Nome del corso`= '" . $tipoCorsi . "'";
      $results = mysqli_query( $link, $querys );
      // $array = array();

      while ( $rows = mysqli_fetch_array( $results ) ) {
        echo( "<th scope='row'>" . $rows[ 'Id' ] . "</th>
             <td>" . $rows[ 'Tipo corso' ] . "</td>
             <td>" . $rows[ 'Nome del corso' ] . "</td>
             <td>" . $rows[ 'Descrizione del corso' ] . "</td>
             <td>" . $rows[ 'Ore teoria' ] . "</td>
             <td>" . $rows[ 'Ore pratica' ] . "l</td>
             <td>" . $rows[ 'Ore fad' ] . "</td>
             <td>" . $rows[ 'Periodicita' ] . "</td>" );
      }
}else {
   echo "Error";
}
```

Where am I doing wrong? I'm going crazy

Thanks for the help

**UPDATE 1**: The values `var tipoCorsi` and `var nomeCorso` came from Dynamic dropdown list with PHP, AJAX & MYSQL and if I try `alert(tipoCorsi)` or `alert(nomeCorso)` the values exist. 
I also tried the php function and it correctly reports the `while`loop.
Finally I voluntarily tried to give error to the php function and in this case it give me back `Error` in alert() Ajax.

**UPDATE 2**: I changed from `$ _POST` to `$ _GET` and the script works correctly. How is it possible?

Comment: Do you have some sample code that is working that you can compare for differences to the code that isn't? If the function hasn't changed but behavior is, then it must be somehow different in the source data.

Comment: In order for AJAX to return anything you must `echo` the response from PHP. You're not echoing anything, save for maybe some empty table cells.

Comment: `It gives me an empty value as a result` - what does that mean exactly? Be specific. `it correctly reports the while loop` - also don't understand what this means? Your browser's devtools will show you exactly what happens. Check the network tab, click the POST request - are the right `data` variables sent?  Check the response, did you get back some HTML?  Side note - you are using jQuery, so the vanilla JS in your `success` callback is out of place. KISS, be consistent - `$('#elencoCorsi').html(data);` is the equivalent in jQuery.

Comment: `It gives me an empty value as a result` : in Ajax function `alert(data)` return empty,no data from echo in PHP. I try `while loop` with manual querys and print `echo` in elaborazione_dati.php. Finally the data variables are sent right, for example `nomeCorso=FORMAZIONE+DIRIGENTI&tipoCorsi=FAD` .

Comment: Glad you solved it, and I can't see why GET/POST would make any difference. However - **your code is wide open to SQL injection**.  Please stop everything and fix that now - [here's the reference SO question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496) with examples.